# footer gets pushed up when you download file

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a footer with following css

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:8rem;
}
```

The idea is to place the footer to the bottom of the page, whether the content of a page is less/more than the size of the screen.

But what's happening is when I download a file on the page, the file download bar that you get at the bottom of the page pushes the footer up. Is there a way to prevent this? This happens in chrome.

```
<div id="page-container">
    <div id="footer">
</div>

#page-container {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? What browser are you using? What do your other elements height look like (percentages, vh, rem, etc...)

Comment: @scottyfullstack Using chrome

Answer (score 1):

The download bar (I assume you are talking about Chrome) is not considered part of the viewport so there is no way to prevent this.